# How to transition to a different animation during the blend phase?

Tags: animation, unity

I have a set of animations: Idle, start walking, stop walking, and walking full speed.

I have the animations all blending nicely...and the controls are fairly responsive during most of the motion...but there are odd transitions where the blends take away control--I can't transition to the walking animations when I am blending between the "stop walking" and "Idle" animations, for instance.

How do I get the animations to transfer during the blend phase??

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold because it does not contain enough information to diagnose the problem and suggest an appropriate fix. We'd need to see the Animator Controller graph and how the transitions have been configured.

Answer (score 0):

If your character controller have variable movement speed value, use it for blending.

Are you using any transition/condition to exit the blend tree and enter into another blend tree?

Use movement float value for transitioning between blend trees as you normally use between states.